# It is not possible to read data from the Firebase database in real time, but the application is connected to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to extract data from Firebase and display it in a TextView. But I can't do it, even though the application is connected to firebase. Logs: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]. FirebaseApp initialization successful. I run the application in the emulator. The device has internet access. Help me, please, I'm at a dead end!
I ran the application in debug mode, but it didn't help. I also tried to create a new project with a new firebase realtime database. I tried to display the data from firebase in the logs, but they are not in the logs either. There are no mistakes. I think I'm doing everything right, but there is no result. [image][image]

```
**MainActivity.java**
`package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("Data");

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                textView.setText(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("Firebase", "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}`
```

**build.gradle(Project:Test)**
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}
}

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

**build.gradle(Module:app)**
`plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.example.test'

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}`
```

**activity_main.xml**
`
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Retrieve Data"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

**AndroidManifest.xml**
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>`
```

Comment: if any error message in logs, then please mention it here. Have you added the `google-services.json` file in your project ?

Comment: There are no errors in the logs. The project has a google-services.json file. The assistant tells me that the application is connected to Firebase.

Comment: Put a log in value event listener to check whether the data is received or not in `value` and try to update `textview` on `ui thread`

Comment: Do you mean this:? String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);

Comment: yes in order to check whether the value event listener is working or not.

Comment: If you try to log the value of `value`, are you getting something printed out in the logcat? Please respond using @AlexMamo